# Binding no-ops or null handlers to Vue event handlers?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Is there a Vue convention or best practice for defining empty event handlers?

Vue's `transition` element includes the convenient, though easily overlooked, `appear` attribute. It uses the transition's `enter` hooks by default, but a separate set of `appear` hooks also becomes available. I have a case where `:appear` should do nothing while `:enter` triggers a function. If `:appear` is not bound, Vue falls back to `:enter`, so something has to be there.

Writing conditional logic into the `enter` hook feels wrong, but I'm not sure how best to define the hook. The following all work, but if there isn't a Vue convention, which should be considered a best practice?

**Boolean attribute**

```html
<transition
  appear
  v-on:appear
  v-on:enter="doEnter"
>
```

**"Empty" attribute**

```html
<transition
  appear
  v-on:appear=""
  v-on:enter="doEnter"
>
```

**Explicit no-op handler**

```html
<transition
  appear
  v-on:appear="doAppear"
  v-on:enter="doEnter"
>
```

```js
new Vue({
  //...
  methods: {
    //...
    doAppear: () => {}
  }
});
```

Some other options could include inline no-op functions `v-on:appear="() => {}"` or abusing JavaScript's "everything is a function" nature with an empty object `v-on:appear="{}"` or number `v-on:appear="0"`. `false` doesn't work, because Booleans aren't functions and `Function` doesn't work because Vue sees a string instead of the bare prototype.

Comment: First option looks clean and expresses the intent quite nicely, IMO.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is much of a noticeable difference unless you benchmark it.

If this matters to you, you could choose to not have the `appear` handler by passing a dynamic object to `v-on` instead.

```
<transition ... v-on="transitionEventHandlers">
```

JS

```js
  data: {
    shouldUseAppearHandler: true
  },
  computed: {
    transitionEventHandlers() {
      let handlers = {
        enter: this.doEnter
      };
      if(this.shouldUseAppearHandler) {
        handlers = {
          appear: this.doAppear,
          ...handlers
        }
      }
      return handlers;
    }
  },
  methods: {
    doEnter() {
      console.log("enter");
    },
    doAppear() {
      console.log("appear");
    }
  }
```

example: https://codepen.io/jacobgoh101/pen/aGVzjR?editors=1011